# Unity animationClip changes don't show up in file status in vcs

Tags: unity-game-engine, version-control, assets, unity-editor

If I change a AnimationClip in the Unity Animation Panel, the changes won't show up in my vcs.

It is not showing in the terminal via git status, nor in the GUI of sourcetree.

How to apply changes effectivly to an animation file?

I'm using Unity 5.6.5f1 on MacOs. (And I can't change the version because it is a project related choice.)

Comment: Have you tried File -> "Save project"??

Comment: What settings did you change? If you change stuff like the import settings, those will be reflected in the .meta file. And you'll have to make sure you've added these meta files to version control.

Comment: @Chopi ahhh good idea, I will try this and tell you how it went. :)

@ Aj_ Meta are of course in vcs and no changes in meta files are shown. I changed the keyframes of the animation. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Chopi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4945060/chopi) correctly suggested in the comments, Unity only applies the changes done in an animation asset when 'Save Project' is executed.